# Layout programmatically created UILabels in a UIView

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview

I have this:

[image]

Created via this piece of code:

```
// Add hashtag collection to a post
func addHashtags(container: UIView, constraint: NSLayoutConstraint) -> Void {

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width - 16 - 16

    var currentOriginX: CGFloat = 0
    var currentOriginY: CGFloat = 0

    for j in 0..<self.pseudo.count {
        if currentOriginY < 144 {
            // Create a new label
            let labelHashtag = RoundedLabel()
            labelHashtag.rounded = true

            tagLabels.append(labelHashtag)

            print(tagLabels.count)

            // Set its properties (title, colors, corners, etc)
            labelHashtag.text = pseudo[j] as? String
            labelHashtag.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .semibold)
            labelHashtag.textAlignment = .center
            labelHashtag.textColor = UIColor.black
            labelHashtag.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            labelHashtag.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.88, green:0.88, blue:0.88, alpha:1.0).cgColor
            labelHashtag.layer.borderWidth = 1

            // Set its frame width and height
            labelHashtag.frame.size.width = labelHashtag.intrinsicContentSize.width + tagPadding
            labelHashtag.frame.size.height = tagHeight

            // Add it to the scroll view
            container.addSubview(labelHashtag)

            // If current X + label width will be greater than container view width
            // .. move to next row

            if (currentOriginX + labelHashtag.frame.width > screenWidth) {
                tagLabels[0].textColor = .red
                print("übrig")
                print(screenWidth - currentOriginX)
                currentOriginX = 0
                currentOriginY += tagHeight + tagSpacingY
            }

            // Set the btn frame origin
            labelHashtag.frame.origin.x = currentOriginX
            labelHashtag.frame.origin.y = currentOriginY

            // Increment current X by btn width + spacing
            currentOriginX += labelHashtag.frame.width + tagSpacingX

        } else if currentOriginY == 90 {
            }

        // Update container view height
        constraint.constant = currentOriginY + tagHeight
        }

    container.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

I want to center all items in each row. I imagine I have to calculate the remaining width of my UIView and add a margin to the first item.

How can I add a margin to my UILabel? I can access it via tagLabels[0] and I think I know how to calculate the remaining width, but I don't know how I can add the margin to it.

Comment: If you can get the remaining width, simply divide by two create a new view and add it, make it opaque and isUserInteractionEnabled = false.

Comment: I understand your approach and like it, but I don't know if this is working in my approach since I loop to create the labels and only see if I have to create a new row if the width exceeds my screen width..?

Comment: Ok so whenever you're checking to see if you have to create a new, simply do your centering there. If you're having to create a new row then you KNOW that you have to center the row that was just filled out.

Comment: Yes - seems legit. Could you give me a little tip, HOW to center..? Thank you!

Comment: Whew there are a million different ways to center it. Personally, the way I'd do it is to add a StackView and add the views to that stack view and set their property to center. That's the easiest and most straightforward. So instead of adding a row the way you're doing create a vertical Stack view and add new horizontal stack views as needed. Then set their property to center, viola done.

Comment: Thanks!! Really appreciate it